# Recursive component template in AngularJs 1.5+

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-components

Recently I've started diving into angularJS. I read some topics about component-based approach and decided the get some practice.
I want to create a component which represents some kind of layered structure of rows.
I have a model for table row and two controllers: for table row and for entire table:

```
export class TreeTableRowModel {
    uniqueKey: string;
    loaded: boolean;
    showChildren: boolean;
    treeLevel: number;  
    cells: any[]; // order corresponds to columns order
    children: TreeTableRowModel[]; 
}

export class TreeTableRowController {
    public tableRowModel: TreeTableRowModel;  

    public constructor() {
        console.log("constructor called");
        console.log(JSON.stringify(arguments.length));
    }   
}   

export class TreeTableController {
    public maxTableInheritanceLevel: number;
    public rows: Array<TreeTableRowModel>;                 
}
```

I've created module, registered controllers and components into this module.
Here is my code for the row component:

```
    import * as angular from "angular";
import { TreeTableRowController } from "./TreeTableRowController.component";

var module = angular.module('treeTable', []);
module.controller('treeTableRowController', TreeTableRowController);
module.component('treeTableRow', {
    bindings: {
        tableRowModel: '<'
    },
    controller: 'treeTableRowController',
    controllerAs: 'row',
    template:   ['<div><span>test row: {{row}}</span></div>',
                '<div><span>test row.tableRowModel: {{row.tableRowModel}}</span></div>',

                '<div class="tree-table-row" ng-repeat="cellData in row.tableRowModel.cells">',  
                    '<span>inside cells ng-repeat test</span>',     
                    '<div class="tree-table-cell">',
                         '<i ng-if="$first" ng-class="row.tree_icon" ng-click="row.showChildren = !row.showChildren" class="indented tree-icon icon-plus fa fa-plus"></i>',
                         '<span>{{cellData}}</span>',
                     '</div>',
                '<div>'].join('')
                //'<treeTableRow ng-if="row.showChildren " ng-repeat="childRows in row.children"></treeTableRow>>' ].join('')    
});
```

And for the table component:

```
    import * as angular from "angular";
import { TreeTableController } from "./TreeTableController";
import "../TreeTableRow/tree-table-row.component"

var module = angular.module('treeTable');
module.controller('treeTableController', TreeTableController );
module.component('treeTable', {
    bindings: {
        rows: '<',
        maxTableInheritanceLevel: '@'
    },
    controller: 'treeTableController',
    controllerAs: 'table',
    template:   ['<div class="tree-table">',
                    '<div class="tree-table-head">',
                        '<div class="tree-table-cell"></div>',
                        '<div class="tree-table-cell"></div>',
                        '<div class="tree-table-cell"></div>',
                        '<div class="tree-table-cell"></div>',
                        '<div class="tree-table-cell"></div>',                        
                        '<div class="tree-table-cell"></div>',        
                    '</div>',
                    '<div class="tree-table-body">', 
                        '<div ng-repeat="tRow in table.rows">',
                            '<span>tRow: {{tRow}}</span>',
                            '<tree-table-row tableRowModel="tRow"></tree-table-row>',
                        '</div>',
                        '<div class="tree-table-cell">',
                            '<span>TEST TEST TEST</span>',
                        '</div>',
                    '</div>',
                '</div>'].join('')    
});
```

With the help of gulp i compile ts files into js files, copy it into output directory and use browserify for bundling, i.e. i have one output file which works fine.

The problem is that code

> `<tree-table-row tableRowModel="tRow">`

doesn't actually set controller's field "tableRowModel" with tRow and i don't know why (tRow is all right, i've seen logs with it). Can someone please give me an idea why it doesn't work and how to fix it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bindings get kebab-cased like the component name strings because of HTML elements/attributes not being case-sensitive, so try doing `<tree-table-row table-row-model="tRow">`.

Comment: Thank you for this mention, it solves issue. I really wasted about 5 hours in order to find the cause why attribute binding is not working in my case :). But the second question arises: is it possible to see logs / debug angular binding process?

Comment: Sure thing. Now you're in good company with all of us who have spent way too much time not noticing that. I think it's a rite of passage for people who are new to AngularJS.

Comment: As far as logging/debugging goes... I'm not sure there's a super straightforward way to do it, but I have two suggestions:

1) define [the $onChanges lifecycle hook (scroll down a bit on this link)](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#component-based-application-architecture) on the component's controller. Something like 
    "controller: function() {
      this.$onChanges = function(changesObj) { console.log(changesObj); };
    }"

2) using Chrome you can [set debugger breakpoints](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/breakpoints)

Comment: Yeah, recently i've found myself setting breakpoints in chrome. I just thought that there should be internal direct angular approach to easily controll the full lifecycle. Seems like $onChanges partially achieves what i need. Thank you once more!